# Which numerical library to use for porting from Matlab to C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, math, numerical-methods, numerical

I am currently prototyping some algorithms in Matlab that rely on matrix, DSP, statistics and image analysis functionality.

Some examples of what I may need:

- eigenvectors
- convolution in 2D and 3D
- FFT
- Short Time Fourier Transform
- Hilbert transform
- Chebyshev polynomials
- low pass filter
- random multivariate gaussian numbers
- kmeans

Later on I will need to implement these algorithms in C++.

I also have a license for Numerical Recipes in C++, which I like because it is well documented and have a wide variety of algorithms.
I also found a class that helps with wrapping NR functions in MEX:[nr3matlab.h](http://www.nr.com/nr3_matlab.html).
So using this class I should be able to generate wrappers that allow me to call NR functions from Matlab. This is very important to me, so that I can check each step when porting from Matlab to C++.
However Numerical Recipes in C++ have some important shortcomings:

- algorithms implemented in a simple, and not necessarily very efficient
  manner
- not threaded

I am therefore considering using another numerical library.
The ideal library should:

- be as broad in scope and functionality as possible
- be well documented
- (have commercial support)
- have already made Matlab wrappers
- very robust
- very efficient
- threaded
- (have a GPU implementation that can be turned
  on instead of the CPU with a "switch")

**Which numerical library (libraries) would you suggest?**

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: List some specific functions/algorithms you're looking for, right now this question is too vague.

Comment: Thanks. Listed some that sprung to mind.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention for future reference that questions like this find a good home on [scicomp.SE].

Comment: @Andy, I've bought `Numerical Recipes in C++`. What a useless library, however the book is amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you should have a look at [openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

Although its first goal is computer vision/image processing, this library has a lot of linear algebra tools (Almost all that you ask for). At first, this library has been implemented by intel, with a lot of focus on performance. It can handle multi thread, IPP,...
The syntax is rather easier to use than usual C++ library.

You should have a look at this [cheat sheet](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=opencv_cheatsheet.pdf). The syntax has been changed since version 2.0 to mimic matlab.
This library is broadly used, and well active (last big update August 2011).

Comment: I'm surprised you have suggested OpenCV instead of  Eigen.

Answer (score 5):

You have a pretty long list of requirements, and it may be challenging to cover them all with a single library.

For general Matlab-to-C++ transitions, I can highly recommend [**Armadillo**](http://arma.sf.net) which is a templated C++ library with a focus on linear algebra --- and a given focus on making it easy to write Matlab-alike expression.  It as very good performance, is very well documented and actively maintained.  You could start there and try to fill in the missing pieces for your task.

Comment: Thanks. Also looks very good. I especially like that it is built upon Lapack whilst provding a much easier and Matlab-like interface.

Comment: On top of BLAS, which is an interface. So you can always drop in faster BLAS instead of default LAPACK.   And Conrad knows his stuff and is a pleasure to work with.

Answer (score 3):

[NAG](http://www.nag.co.uk/) could be one good option. Loads of financial institutions use it in their mathematical libraries. Don't have a GPU implementation though, when I last used it.

Comment: Thanks. Looks very good. Do you know approximately how much 1 developer license cost?

Comment: @ Andreas Werner Paulsen - Google found out this. http://www.eduserv.org.uk/lns/agreements/nag/nag-pricing. Not sure how much it helps you. Educational institutions get preferential pricing, seems from their website.

Answer (score 2):

there is also the Eigen library: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org
but it is mostly used as part of a larger framework. It offers basic (and a bit more complex) algebra

Comment: It's a tour de force of c++ templating, but compiles are slow and error messages can be terribly long (terrible *and* long).